# Receiving error builtins.AttributeError: 'pygame.font.Font' object has no attribute 'SysFont' for font and can't figure out why?

Tags: python, text, fonts, pygame

I'm working with pygame and I have text through out my code using

```
font = font.SysFont("candara", 35)
```

using this font, the program is working smoothly and the text shows up

but when I added another font

```
font2 = font.SysFont("arial", 25)
```

I'm getting an error and the text won't work.

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'pygame.font.Font' object has no attribute 'SysFont'
```

This is where I'm using my new font

```
def button4(X):                                                
        draw.rect(X,PINK,(50,70,200,50))
        buttonText = font2.render("Home Country",False,(0,0,0))
        screen.blit(buttonText,(55,80))
```

and this is the beginning of my code;

```
from pygame import *
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(0, 0)
init()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

when you make it :

```
font = font.SysFont("candara", 35)
```

you rewrite `font` variable from `pygame.font` try it for example

```
candara_font = font.SysFont("candara", 35)
```

and after this go on with it

```
arial_font = font.SysFont("arial", 25)
```